# Is there a difference between using a type parameter vs its upper bound in method references?

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

I was making my mock exam for Java programming and I came to a question.
This is a method that we made up in class so that is right.

```
private List<String> zetOmNaarLijstVanString(List<? extends Object> lijst){
    return lijst.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This is the method I made.

```
private <E> List<String> zetOmNaarLijstVanString(List<E> lijst){
    return lijst.stream().map(E::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

The difference is in the second method. I made the whole method generic. I don't really know if this is a fault since I don't see a difference between the 2 methods now.

Could someone help me out to see a difference (If there is one)?

Comment: The `<E>` after the private keyword in the second method only declares that you can now use the `E` as a type in the rest of the method declaration and definition. I believe both methods will work the same.

Comment: There is no difference, except you're forcing the compiler to through the process of resolving `E`, but it's still so fast that you're not going to feel any compiler performance difference.

Comment: First one appears a lot clearer and less verbose for me, in this particular example you don't need a generic parameter of `E`. You could modify parameter of your first method to `List<?>` which means the same as `? extends Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular example, there is no difference. To extend this a bit further to see the actual difference, you could use this as an example:

Compiles and runs just fine because we know the list only contains Strings

```
private List<String> replaceAWithB(List<? extends String> list) {
    return list.stream().map(s -> s.replaceAll("a","b")).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Will not compile because we do not know that E is a String

```
private <E> replaceAWithB(List<E> list) {
    return list.stream().map(s -> s.replaceAll("a","b")).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: The second example only fails to compile because the upper bound of E is ``Object`` (implicitly). If you write ``private <E extends String>``, it will compile. I am not sure how the example contributes to answering the question.